# Trigger 3055 Transistor from 100mA 3V base

Tags: transistors

I'm looking for an NPN transistor that I can use to switch a 3055 transitor.  The base of the transitor I need should switch using the GPIO output from a Raspberry Pi ~3v @ 100mA.

The 3055 needs to put out 14V at about 1 amp.  Anybody got any suggestions?  Or if anyone could explain the gain I need to be looking for to make this work, I'd be glad to look around.

By the way, a very high speed switching darlington may be worth considering. However the 3055 needs to put out a perfect square wave.

Comment: Why don't you use a MOSFET instead? Requires no current to switch on.

Comment: No such thing as a perfect square wave. Instead of trying to explain what you think you need by referencing bits of circuit you think might work, try explaining what functionality and performance you want.

Comment: I'll take a look at MOSFET options and see what might work.

Comment: Andy, Square wave as in as square as possible.  Ideally that's with a maximum of a 20uS trail off on the waveform.  The project I am working on is converting an old analog system to a digital interface. The analog system generates a square wave in the range of 100--300Hz that drives a transmitter coil with a current of about 400mA at 14v.  I know the analog system works like a charm.  The key is the interface from the GPIO pin and the output transistor to be able to deliver that wattage in a near-perfect square wave.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just as a follow up.  I went with Rohat's idea and used a MOSFET, which seems to be working great.  Specifically I used an NET2980.  Thanks for the recommendation.